# Stacks and data Structures

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I am doing an assignment for class and it requires me to Develop an algorithm using the Java programming language that implements a basic stack data structure.

Here is the scenario: Assume that you are developing a system for a manufacturing assembly line that builds automobiles. There are three stations in the manufacturing line where an inspector will visually inspect the vehicle. You program must keep track of these inspections as they occur. You decided to develop your program using a stack data structure. As your vehicle begins the line you will push the number 0, which indicates that that an inspection has not yet occurred, onto the stack three subsequent times. At each station in the line you will pop one of the items off of the stack. Each time your algorithm pops an item from the stack you must print it out to the console using the system.out.println function. I will post my code below. Does my code represent this senario?

My Code:

```
import jeliot.io.*;

public class MyStack {
   private int maxSize;
   private long[] stackArray;
   private int top;
   public MyStack(int s) {
      maxSize = s;
      stackArray = new long[maxSize];
      top = -1;
   }
   public void push(long j) {
      stackArray[++top] = j;
   }
   public long pop() {
      return stackArray[top--];
   }
   public long peek() {
      return stackArray[top];
   }
   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return (top == -1);
   }
   public boolean isFull() {
      return (top == maxSize - 1);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyStack theStack = new MyStack(5); 
      theStack.push(0);
      theStack.push(1);
      theStack.push(2);
      theStack.push(3);
      theStack.push(4);
      while (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
         long value = theStack.pop();
         System.out.print(value);
         System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
   }
 }
```

The assignment also came with a linked list example code. You can compare how my code works as to the example. Here is the code:

```
import Prog1Tools.IOTools;

class Node {
   Node ptr;
   int value;
   public Node(int value) {
     this.value = value;
   }
}

public class CreateLinkedList {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node link, plink;
    // root will be the beginning of the linked list
    Node root = new Node(5);
    // each additional node will link to preceeding one
    link = new Node(1);
    link.ptr = root;
    plink = link;

    link = new Node(8);
    link.ptr = plink;
    plink = link;

    link = new Node(6);
    link.ptr = plink;
    plink = link;

    link = new Node(3);
    link.ptr = plink;
    plink = link;

    // Move through the list and print out each value
    printList(link);
}

public static void printList(Node node) {
  if (node != null) {
    System.out.println(" Value: " + node.value);
    printList(node.ptr);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your code represent this scenario?

Comment: Yes as in would it work for the scenario?

Comment: I'll throw it right back at you, does your code work for this scenario?

Comment: @Liwizy It's unclear what you're asking.  If you're asking if it will work, just run it and find out.

Comment: @Liwizy "As your vehicle begins the line you will push the number 0, which indicates that that an inspection has not yet occurred, onto the stack three subsequent times.".

Comment: Well the code runs perfectly fine in Jeliot 3. I am just try to get another opinion on whether or not  what i have written is suitable.

Comment: The assignment says to push the value `0` 3 times when a new assembly starts. Yet I see you pushing `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`. So unless I am misunderstanding something, it seems like you did it wrong.

Comment: As an aside, it is not clear to me how your program "must keep track of these inspections as they occur." How does your program know when an inspection occurs? Is it supposed to take some kind of input from a user when a vehicle goes onto the line / gets inspected?

Comment: i think you're missing the "three stations" part, the problem is not clear to me.. is it for you?

Comment: If I got this homework problem, I would have to ask the teacher to explain it better before I tried to implement it. I don't understand the instructions in the original assignment.

Comment: That part was confusing to me as well, and I have asked for an explanation but the teacher has not gotten back to me as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the stack data structure is well implemented.

Answer (score 0):

or you could just extend already existing stack implementation to add some specific behavior (like printing out popped elements)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html